# Im getting a error about in a manifest json i cant locate when serving my vue project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, manifest.json

So this is the error i get when i open my vue project... except that i cant even locate my manifest.json nore do i have a /img/icons folder in the project. I cannot figure out what the error is or how to correct it

> Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:8080/img/icons/android->chrome-192x192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is typically caused by altering a project created using Vue Cli 3's command `vue create some-project` and then removing either parts of or in its entirety the `public` folder. Namely, the error complains about the absence of icon files situated in `public/img/icons`, aimed at providing android, apple or web icons/favicons for the served/built app.

A possible fix for this error is to create a new project (run `vue create whatever` outside of your project) and copy-paste the resulting `public/` folder into your current project.

If you haven't created your project with Vue Cli 3, the solution above will likely not work.
For Vue Cli 2.x projects, according to [Vue Cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#pulling-2-x-templates-legacy) running `vue init webpack my-project` in the root of the project (where `my-project` is the name of your project as set in `package.json`) might work.